# Update any field when contains value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table in MySQL db, let's say `test_table`

```
| ENTRY_ID | A1       | A2       | A3       | A4       | A5       | A6       |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 11       | 12       | 13       | 14       | 15       | 16       |
| 2        | 22       | 23       | 24       | 25       | 26       | 27       |
| 3        | 32       | 33       | 34       | 35       | 36       | 37       |
...
```

What I would like to achieve is to update IN ONE QUERY to NULL the row/field that contains, e.g. value 16 (of course it can be any other value). So after that my table will looks like:

```
| ENTRY_ID | A1       | A2       | A3       | A4       | A5       | A6       |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 11       | 12       | 13       | 14       | 15       | NULL     |
| 2        | 22       | 23       | 24       | 25       | 26       | 27       |
| 3        | 32       | 33       | 34       | 35       | 36       | 37       |
...
```

And then if I would like to remove value, e.g. 24 it will look like:

```
| ENTRY_ID | A1       | A2       | A3       | A4       | A5       | A6       |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 11       | 12       | 13       | 14       | 15       | NULL     |
| 2        | 22       | 23       | NULL     | 25       | 26       | 27       |
| 3        | 32       | 33       | 34       | 35       | 36       | 37       |
...
```

Sounds easy but this is complicated as I do not know which column exactly stores which values... Value 16 can be in `A6`  or `A1` or `A2` ... etc. The only guarantee I have is that values are unique in the whole table. There is no way that one row (or few rows) will have the same, e.g. 16, value. So, in short, I can't use something like `UPDATE test_table SET A6 = NULL WHERE A6 = 16`. I rather need something like (pseudocode): `UPDATE test_table SET ANY_FIELD = NULL WHERE CONTAINS(ANY_FIELD, 16)`

I am not even sure if this is possible but I believe in power of MySQL and you guys :)

The worst case is to get row that contains that value, get the field name and then do normal update.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to loop over tall the columns, you have to list them all explicitly, using `NULLIF()` to conditionalize.

```
UPDATE test_table
SET a1 = NULLIF(a1, 16),
    a2 = NULLIF(a2, 16),
    a3 = NULLIF(a3, 16),
    ...
WHERE 16 IN (a1, a2, a3, ...)
```

Comment: DUUUUUUUUDE... It works! I didn't know about that possibility, thanks ! Solved :)